# Which casing of property names is considered the "most correct" in a Google Cloud Pub/Sub Push Message?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

If you use [a "Push" subscription to a Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push), you'll be registering an HTTPS endpoint that receives messages from Google's managed service. This is great if you wish to avoid dependencies on Google Cloud's SDKs and instead trigger your asynchronous services via a traditional web request. However, the intended casing of the properties of the payload is not clear, and since I'm using Push subscriptions I don't have a SDK to defer to for deserialization.

<strike>If you look at [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#receive_push), you see references to `message_id` using [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case)</strike> (**Update 9/18/18:** As stated in [Kamal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53834746/735679), the documentation was updated since this was incorrect), e.g.:

```json
{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
    "message_id": "136969346945",
    "publish_time": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
}
```

If you look at [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage), you see references to `messageId` using [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case), e.g.:

```json
{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
    "messageId": "136969346945",
    "publishTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
}
```

If you subscribe to the topics and log the output, you actually get *both* formats, e.g.:

```json
{
  "message": {
    "attributes": {
      "key": "value"
    },
    "data": "SGVsbG8gQ2xvdWQgUHViL1N1YiEgSGVyZSBpcyBteSBtZXNzYWdlIQ==",
    "messageId": "136969346945",
    "message_id": "136969346945",
    "publishTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z",
    "publish_time": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z"
  },
  "subscription": "projects/myproject/subscriptions/mysubscription"
}
```

An ideal response would answer both of these questions:

1. Why are there two formats?
2. Is one more correct or authoritative?

Comment: Different programming languages use different conventions for parameter and variable naming. However, I never noticed this about Pub/Sub. Json is typically camelCase but snake_case is also popular. You probably won't get an absolute answer, so always refer to the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The officially correct names for the variables should be camel case (`messageId`), based on the [Google JSON style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml?showone=Property_Name_Format#Property_Name_Format). In the early phases of Cloud Pub/Sub, snake case was used for `message_id` and `publish_time`, but was changed later in order to conform to style standards. The snake case ones were kept in addition to the camel case ones in order to ensure push endpoints depending on the original format did not break. The first documentation link you point apparently was not updated at the time and it will be fixed shortly.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad _this_ documentation is correct as well: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/support#stack-overflow